# How do I access the MouseEventArgs class inside the EventArgs class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to react to the click of a radio button control.  At runtime the EventArgs variable shows an element of type MouseEventArgs which has a base class of type EventArgs as shown in this image.

[image]

The red arrow shows where I'm casting the EventArgs as a MouseEventArgs to allow compilation since without a cast the only methods available are equals, getHashCode, getType and ToString.  One note, I am creating this control manually - not in the designer.

However, if I let it continue I get the following error.

[image]

I understand the error but I am unable to figure out how to get it to compile since 'EventArgs' does not have a Clicks method accessible.

Thanks for any help you all can offer.

Comment: Are you handling the _Click_ or the _MouseClick_?

Comment: Are e.GetType().FullName and typeof(MouseEventArgs).FullName the same in the debugger?

Comment: Are you referencing the right MouseEventArgs class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx vs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the second parameter of your event handler of having type `MouseEventArgs`. Like this:

```
private static void AutoMan_RadBut_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

That way, you don't have to cast the argument within the method.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the cast is failing, if the delegate really does define a `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But there are enough questions (see the comments above) left unanswered about the problem, that this answer could lead to figuring out what's really going on behind the scenes.

Comment: techniques for diagnosing a problem are better suited for comments, not answers.

Comment: However, my answer still describes something that should be done anyway and does answer the first half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses.

The final solution used part of Adam's answer.  I needed to change the EventArgs to  MouseEventArgs but that caused an error all by itself.  The whole solution included changing

```
new EventHandler(AutoMan_RadBut_Click);
```

to

```
new MouseEventHandler(AutoMan_RadBut_Click)
```

Thanks Adam for putting me on the right path.

P.S. I still don't know why 'e' has a MouseEventArgs sub-class at run-time but I can't access it at compile time.